# Can anyone recommend Apache2 indicator for gnome panel

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator, apache2

I just re-install my Ubuntu and forgot name of Apache2 service indicator, it's a green button at start and red at stop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're referring to [apache-switch](http://apache-switch.webuda.com/)?

It's quite easy though to do it by hand:

`sudo service apache2 (start|stop|restart)`